# VLOOKUP in last column of Table_array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I understand that VLOOKUP searches the first column of a table in order to find a value, then it grabs the value from the same row and a different user-specified column. The following code returns data from the 2nd column, column B.

```
VLOOKUP(5,$A$2:B100,2)
```

Is there a way to set the return column to the last column of the input table? Something like the following, which would return data from columns B, P, and AC, respectively.

```
VLOOKUP(5,$A$2:B100,end)
VLOOKUP(5,$A$2:P100,end)
VLOOKUP(5,$A$2:AC100,end)
```

Alternatively, is there a way to grab the current column number and use that as an index?

```
VLOOKUP(5,$A$2:B100,current_column_number)
```

I'd like to write one VLOOKUP formula and then be able to drag it right across the spreadsheet, so that B100 becomes C100, D100, E100, etc. and the column lookup changes accordingly.

### Update

I can do the alternate approach using the COLUMN function, but it requires programming a fixed offset and doesn't seem as robust. I'd still like to know if there is an "end" option.

Comment: 1. There is no *end* option. 2. As none of your [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) examples uses the optional *range_lookup* parameter, I would remind you that without it, the first column must be sorted ascending for the function to work correctly as the default for *range_lookup* is TRUE. An exact match on unsorted data can be made by setting *range_lookup* to FALSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=VLOOKUP(5,$A$2:B100,COLUMNS($A$2:B100))
```

Unfortunately you cannot simply drag it, you'll need to replace as there are two equivalent ranges written in the nested function.
The COLUMNS effectively counts the columns in the range giving the exact result needed for the VLOOKUP's *end* variant.

**EDIT** to show OP what a simple drag function would be like:

```
Function VLOOKUP2(Expected As Variant, Target As Range)
x = Target.Columns.Count
VLOOKUP2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Expected, Target, x)
End Function
```

Comment: "Unfortunately you cannot simply drag it"?

The COLUMNS function does exactly what I was looking for with _end_, and it looks like I can drag it.

Comment: Yeah, but on initial highlighting, you'll need to find the area twice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Excel `COLUMN()` function to convert the column reference to a numerical index into the `VLOOKUP` table.  Try this:

```
VLOOKUP(5, $A$2:B100, COLUMN(B2))
VLOOKUP(5, $A$2:P100, COLUMN(P2)
VLOOKUP(5, $A$2:AC100, COLUMN(AC2))
```

In pratice, you can just enter the first formula I gave above and then copy to the right.  Each copy will automatically shift the column number to the end.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the count function while holding (`$`) one side of the count range, thus giving you an integer that `Vlookup` can use.

Something like:

```
VLOOKUP(5,$A$2:B100,COUNT($A$2:A2))
```

You may need to add a `+` or `-` `1` to the count function depending on where your range starts.

It's effectively doing the same thing you already did with the array for the vlookup